# Max. external ADC speed with ESP32 (SPI or I2C)?

Tags: i2c, esp32, spi, adc

What is the maximum speed for external ADC I can expect to get with ESP32? I'm planning to have 16-bit ADC connected to I2C or SPI whichever gives more speed.

How that information is calculated from information in ESP data sheet?

Comment: Depends on the ADC and what technology it uses. Instead you should be asking what would be a suitable way of sampling whatever it is you want to sample. SPI will always be faster than I2C, but neither may be the right system to use. We need more detail about what you want to achieve.

Comment: How fast do you want it, or: how fast is you adc? There are different options to interface the spi/i2c peripherals (polling, interrupt, dma).

Comment: I2S is even faster, and supported on the 32.